# Replace a list of DataFrames if it matches a condition with Dataframes from another list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 lists of DF.

```
list_dfs1=[df1,df2,df3...df100]
list_dfs2=[df1,df2,df3,df4,df5]
list_of_index=[16,22,38,87,98]
```

The idea was to replace the Dataframes from list 1 with the Dataframes in list 2 if it matches a condition.

e.g 1. i get the last df from the second list to reflect (df5) on all that matches the condition. Why?

```
for i, df in enumerate(list_dfs1):
    for index, x in enumerate(list_dfs2):
        if len(df.columns)<=4:
            list_dfs1[i]=list_dfs2[index]
```

e.g 2: Here i get the whole list_dfs2 replacing the Dataframes that matches the condition.

```
for i, df in enumerate(list_dfs1):
    list_dfs1[i]=[x for x in list_dfs2 if len(df.columns)<=4]
```

Any suggestions.

Note: list_dfs2 was originally extracted from list_dfs1 with the same condition. Now I want to put them again after I have done some amendment to them. That means I already expect the same count

Comment: Your `list_dfs2` has only 5 dataframes. If, for example dataframe no.27 from `list_dfs1` has number of columns greater than 4, to which dataframe it needs to change?

Comment: if df27 doesn't match the condition, it stays the same. Doesn't need to change

Comment: And if matches the condition, to what it changes?

Comment: Since list 2 was originally made based on the same condition. It should be replaced again in the same index it originated from. E.g. df27 when it was originally extracted was named df2 in list 2.

Comment: But is there some formula how to compute index in list2 from index in list1?

Comment: I didn't understand the question!

Comment: For example, dataframe 48 in list1 matches the condition. How I, as a programmer, should know which dataframe should I chose from list2 to replace this dataframe?

Comment: Ok. Since List 2 was made with the same condition originally (filter list 1 with columns <=4 append to list 2). By filtering List 1 again with the same condition we should have the same count of elements in both lists. Now what i am trying to do is to replace based on the position of elements from both lists.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to the problem

```
for i, dfindex in enumerate(list_of_indexes):
    list_dfs1[dfindex]=list_dfs2[i]
```